# TYPO3 query condition 'in' by mm relation

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18.

I have model 'meeting'
In DB table I have field 'category_type' and this can only values 0 or 1, because it mm relation to other table.

I tried make query condition

```
$query->in('categoryType', array(0 => 2));
```

2 - it's uid of object from relation table (category_type)
and it does't work.
But the next code works:

```
$query->in('categoryType', array(0 => 1));
```

So problem is that it not use mm relation objectStorage, it just check 'categorytype' field.

model 'meeting'

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Istar\Femeeting\Domain\Model\CategoryType>
 */
protected $categoryType = 0;

/**
 * Returns the categoryType
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Istar\Femeeting\Domain\Model\CategoryType> $categoryType
 *
 */
public function getCategoryType()
{
    return $this->categoryType;
}

/**
 * Sets the categoryType
 *
 * @param $categoryType
 * @return void
 */
public function setCategoryType($categoryType)
{
    $this->categoryType = $categoryType;
}
```

TCA 'meeting'

```
'category_type' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:femeeting/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:categoryType',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_femeeting_domain_model_categorytype',
        'MM' => 'tx_femeeting_domain_model_categorytype_mm',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_femeeting_domain_model_categorytype.sys_language_uid=###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid### ',
        'maxitems' => '50',
        'multiple' => 1,
    ),
),
```

I hope you understand my problem. I really need help( Is it possible to make this condition ? I need that it get meetings where 'meeting.category_type' in [2,4,5]. meeting.category_type - that's object storage. Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me please) I am not attention ) 
$query->in('categoryType.uid', $categories);   "uid" - that's was a problem